# Show students extra credit as 12/10 and regular result as 10/10 using rubric

Tags: google-classroom

I have an assignment that is graded as 10 credits, but I give 2 extra credit points within the assignment.

Part of my rubric can give 8 points, and another part can give 4 points.

However, I'd like the students to see 12/10 when I return the assignment or 10/10.  I don't want them to see 10/12 because they'll think they didn't get an A.

Is this possible in Google Classroom?

Answer (score 0):

**Grading in Google Classroom**

I have worked with multiple teachers over my organization requesting this type of feature, unfurtunetevely this feature is not currently available in Classroom.  I encourage you to send this feature request to the Classroom team by clicking on the `?` button on the bottom left of your Classroom screen and selecting "Report issue or request feature.":

[image]

I notice that during the last 2 years, a lot of features that were requested for Classroom have been released like meetings, better calendar integration and similar stuff for the interface, requesting features to better manage it for teachers to work from home have been excellent.

You could also make the request here:

- https://developers.google.com/classroom/support

Under missing features for Classroom API, it would be a good alternative if possible to be able to provide an option to edit or build something similar if not available from the web interface.

Edit:

Suggested sample view by the teachers of the organization on what could be added to the feature request and how the grading using rubric could affect how students might see their score:

[image]

**References:**

- https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020294
- https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/9184995